# In-App Provision with Google Pay for Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-pay

Has anyone done In-App provisioning of Google Pay with Xamarin
The google docs on the push-provisioning-api says
"The Push Provisioning API is not available in the publicly distributed version of Google Play Services. You must add the modules available below to the public SDK to use this API."
and gives instructions on how to do this using Gradle for Android projects, but I don't use Gradle in a Xamarin project.

The Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Wallet package is about adding a PayNow button, but I want to add "Add to G Wallet" button.

Is there any other documentation on how to do that using Xamarin? Or has anyone else tried this?

I have looked into trying to create a Xamarin Binding project for the additional "Google Play services SDK libraries ", but I get an error trying to compile that:

*"The type or namespace name 'ITapAndPay' does not exist in the namespace 'Com.Google.Android.Gms.Tapandpay'"*

and I'm not sure what other assemblies/packages I should be referencing.

Comment: Can you please share the respective google docs link that you mentioned that would help thanks

Comment: Unfortunately the Google Push Provisioning API docs are not publicly available-  they are only available if your email address has been white listed.
The link is https://developers.google.com/pay/issuers/push-provisioning-api/releases if you are whitelisted

Answer (score 0):

I did get the Xamarin Binding project to work. The were various issues around the version dependencies of the other Google libraries

I had use the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices preview builds to ensure I got the correct version of the play servies to match the Google Pay library I was binding.
I also to create my own binding of the Google Identity services to match the versions.

Unfortunately I can't share a working solution, but message me if you are having similar issues